# For acumatica, how do I disable a field when Override Contact is unticked?

Tags: c#, acumatica

When the override contact checkbox is unticked, all the fields in that section are disabled so you can't modify them. However, I've recently added a new Attention field, which for some reason doesn't disable itself like the other fields when the override isn't enabled.

[image: Attention Field]

[image: Override Contact]

Is there some kind of attribute that I need to add to make it look out for whether this Override Contact field is checked?

This is how the Attention field has been set up:

```
[PXDBString(50)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Contact")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Contact.displayName,
LeftJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Contact.bAccountID>>>,
Where<Contact.contactType, Equal<ContactTypesAttribute.person>>>))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(
    Where<Current<PMContact.customerID>,
            Like<Contact.bAccountID>>), "")]
```

Thanks for any assistance on this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acumatica probably achieves this through an event handler on the graph. You should be able to accomplish the same end result by adding the following attribute and changing the [DAC.Field] value.

```
[PXUIEnabled(typeof(Where<[DAC.Field].IsEqual<True>>))]
```

This will enable the field the attribute is applied to when the field in the Where clause is set to true, and will disable the field the attribute is applied to when the field in the Where clause is set to false.

If you need a more concrete example, let me know what screen and tab you are on and I can provide a better example with the exact field value for you to use.